# Dependency Injection and Interfaces in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Coming from a C# background, I used interfaces to base my mock objects off of.  I created custom mock objects myself and created the mock implementation off a C# interface.

How do you do something like this in JS or node?  Create an interface that you can "mock" off of and also the interface would serve for the real class that would also be able to implement that interface?  Does this even make sense in JS or or the Node World?

For example in Java, same deal, define an interface with method stubs and use that as the basis to create real class or mock class off of.

Comment: Read more about prototypal inheritance. :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Unless you have default behaviors that you want to inherit from, there's no real use for inheriting from a mock interface in Javascript.  Just define a new object with the desired methods.  Since objects don't have class types in JS, any object with the right methods and properties will work for your purpose.  It doesn't have to inherit from some common base.  Of course, if there are some default behaviors that are useful, then you can inherit from an object that implements those defaults.

Comment: the problem with creating a new object with required methods is you can get out of sync with the contract.  Lets say I have realController and mockController.  If my realController has methods find(), delete() and update() and my fakeController I create has a find(), delete() and add() where add() really means update() I have the potential of having a ton of inconsistent mocks of other objects and now my mocks aren't even a mock of the other object.  At least with interfaces the editor forced me to adhere to the contract...A contract that both the real and fake abide to

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're not going to find the standard interface as a part of JavaScript. I've never used C#, but I've used Java, and correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're talking about creating interfaces and overriding methods for both mock testing purposes, as well as being able to implement those interfaces in other classes.

Because this isn't a standard JavaScript feature, **I think you'll find that there are going to be a lot of very broad answers here**. However, to get an idea of how some popular libraries implement this, I might suggest looking at how AngularJS looks at mock testing (there are many resources online, just Google it. As a starting point, look at how they use the [`ngMock`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) module with Karma and Jasmine.)

Also, because of JavaScript's very flexible nature, **you'll find that you can override any sort of "class method"** (that is, any function object that is a member of another object, whether that be a `new`'ed "class" or a plain object) by simply re-implementing it wherever you need to... there's no special syntax for it. To understand where and how you would accomplish this, I'd suggest looking from the ground up at **how JavaScript using prototypal/prototypical inheritance**. A starting point might be considering an example like this:

```
function Cat(config) {
  if(typeof config !== 'undefined') {
    this.meow = config.meow; // where config can possibly implement certain mock methods
  }
}

Cat.prototype = {
  this.meow = function() {
    // the meow that you want to use as part of your "production" code
  };
};

var config = {};

config.meow = function() {
  // some mock "meow" stuff
};

var testCat = new Cat(config); // this one will use the mock "Cat#meow"

var realCat = new Cat(); // this one will use the prototype "Cat#meow"
```

In the above example, because of how JavaScript looks up the prototype chain, if it sees an implementation in the class itself, it'll stop there and use that method (thus, you've "overridden" the prototype method). However, in that example, if you don't pass in a `config`, then it'll look all the way up to the prototype for the `Cat#meow` method, and use that one.

**TL;DR**: there's not one good way to implement JavaScript interfaces, especially ones that double as mocks (there's not even a best way to implement dependency injection... that's also a foreign concept to JavaScript itself, even though many libraries do successfully implement it for cetain use-cases.)

Comment: "but it looks like you're talking about creating interfaces and overriding methods for both mock testing purposes, as well as being able to implement those interfaces in other classes."  yup exactly.

Comment: I am trying to use Sinon.js but just starting to look at that.  If I have for example myController which has a find() method on it, I guess I could use Sinon to mock it.

Comment: "re-implementing it wherever you need to"  sorry what do you mean by this..how so?

Comment: so basically I can't get away with just using Node Modules in a production application.  I'd have to start using Prototypes if I really wanted to create CUSTOM mocks from scatch (as opposed to using a mock framework).

Comment: If my reply above is true this means I'd start to use prototypes a lot in pretty much all my Node code, inside my modules?   OR would you use prototypes instead of node modules or both in combination...I'd assume both dependingon what you're doing.  You might have pure modules with no prototypes inside and then you might have a node module with all prototype code inside...

Comment: @WeDoTDD, prototypes aren't anything special in regards to mocks... in fact, they are the fundamental "seed" so-to-speak for all JavaScript objects. A prototype to JavaScript is like a class in C#, or a class in Java, or wherever. Just about every object in JavaScript has a prototype. Going to a meeting now, I will add more to my reply soon...